# calling a method from another project in eclipse hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

When trying to call to another project it gives me a

> `java.lang.NullPointerException`

When I try to debug to the called method it informs that

> `source is not found. Edit Source Lookup Path`

I did try to click & add the Path still the same error and also I added the other project to other build path.

What could be the problem?

Comment: How do you expect us to help you without showing your code?

Comment: That *another* project must be in your `lib` packages

Comment: @Ravinder: I add it on Java Build Path -> Projects tab

Comment: @moffeltje: Sorry might be lacking of information maybe you could give me a concept on how to deal with this...  syntax has no errors I can call it directly but when it goes to the controller criteria area in hibernate it gives sources not found

Comment: is this a web app? Also, post the trace for `NullpointerException`